# How to repeat a URL using the hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, urls

**Problem:**

I have a URL that I need to repeat multiple times over several chapters in a document but after looking and trying to use the `hyperref` package I was not successful.

**Code:**

I included the package using `\usepackage{hyperref}`, then I added the URL using the following:

```
\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}
```

Whenever I try to call it using `\ref{}` the URL will not be printed.

**Desired outcome:**

Label a URL and reference to it multiple times throughout a document.

Comment: That is not what `label` and `ref`, and for that matter, `hyperref` is meant for.

Comment: But if it is an academic publication, it may be worthwhile putting the url in either the citation or the end notes and refer to it using the usual citation mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your preamble write

```
\newcommand\kexxcreamGoogleUrl{\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}}
```

and in your body, whenever you want to insert the Google hyperlink, call the macro

```
the answer to this can be easily found, for example, by searching 
on \kexxcreamGoogleUrl.
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I received the following error message when I tried this: `Undefined control sequence. \kexxcreamGoogleUrl -> \href {http://www.google.com}{Google} l.741 \kexxcreamGoogleUrl`

Comment: Did you load hyperref? (`\usepackage{hyperref}`)

Comment: My apologies, I loaded it first but managed to rewind my edits with CMD+Z. Now everything works correctly. I greatly appreciate your time in helping me with this issue.